# Merging a HTTP Server and a Net Server in Node.js

Tags: node.js

For a school project we had to develop a file server and also a chat server. I did both in Node.js. Now I have to merge them, but they're both supposed to listen on the same port.

I have two file which both work. The chat server uses

```
net.createServer(function (socket){
...
}}).listen(9020);
```

And the file server uses

```
http.createServer(function (request, response){
...
}}).listen(9020);
```

Simple putting all the code in the same file returns an error since you can't have two servers listening on the same port. What's the best way to merge them? Can all the code be run in either the Net or HTTP server? I've tried this but it isn't working for me.

Here's the full code:

chat.js

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];
var chat = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {
socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  // Identify this client
  socket.name = "unknown"

  // Put this new client in the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Send a nice welcome message and announce
  socket.write("Welcome to Michael's chat room" + "\r\n");
  //broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\r\n", socket);

  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    var textdata = data.toString();
    if(textdata.trim() === "adios"){
        broadcast("closing connection", socket);
        socket.end();
    }
    else if (textdata.trim() === "help"){
        broadcast("*******************Available commands:*******************\r\nhelp                              Display the program options\r\ntest: <words>                     Send a test message of <words> that does not get logged\r\nname: <chatname>                  Set name to <chatname>\r\nget                               Get the entire chat log\r\npush: <stuff>                     Add <stuff> to the chat log\r\ngetrange <startline> <endline>    Get contents of the chat log from <startline> to <endline>\r\nadios                             Close connection");
    }
    else if (startsWith(textdata, "name:")){
      var rmv = "name: ";
      textdata = textdata.slice( textdata.indexOf( rmv ) + rmv.length );
      socket.name = textdata.trim();
      broadcast("OK\r\n", socket);
    }
    else if (startsWith(textdata, "push:")){
      var rmv = "push: ";
      textdata = textdata.slice( textdata.indexOf( rmv ) + rmv.length );
      textdata = textdata.trim();
      chat.push(socket.name + ": " + textdata + "\r\n");
      broadcast("OK\r\n");
    }
    else if (startsWith(textdata, "test:")){ //Why do we even have this lever?
      var rmv = "test: ";
      textdata = textdata.slice( textdata.indexOf( rmv ) + rmv.length );
      broadcast(textdata.trim() + "\r\n");
    }
    else if (textdata.trim() === "get"){
      for (var i = 0; i < chat.length; ++i) {
        //if (i < 1){
        //        broadcast(chat[i].toString(), socket);
        //}
        //else{
              broadcast(chat[i].toString(), socket);
        //}
      }
    }
    else if (startsWith(textdata, "getrange")){
      var rmv = "getrange ";
      textdata = textdata.slice( textdata.indexOf( rmv ) + rmv.length );

      var newtextdata = textdata;
          newtextdata = newtextdata.split(" ");
      var stringArray = new Array();
      for(var i =0; i < newtextdata.length; i++){
          stringArray.push(newtextdata[i]);
          if(i != newtextdata.length-1){
              //stringArray.push(" ");
          }
      }

      for (var i = stringArray[0]; i <= stringArray[1]; ++i) {
        broadcast(chat[i].toString() + "\r\n", socket);
      }
    }
    else{
    broadcast("Error: unrecognized command: " + textdata + "\r\n", socket);
    }
  });

  // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
  socket.on('end', function () {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\r\n");
  });

  // Send a message to all clients
  function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      // Don't want to send it to sender
      ///if (client === sender) return;    //actually want to send a lot of stuff only to sender - how to do this?
      client.write(message);
    });
    // Log it to the server output too
    process.stdout.write(message)
  }

  function startsWith(str, word) {
    return str.lastIndexOf(word, 0) === 0;
}

socket.on('Error', function(err){
console.log("well heck, there's been an error")
});

}).listen(9020);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 9020\r\n");
```

file.js

```
//based heavily off of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Node_server_without_framework
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log('request ', request.url);

    var filePath = '.' + request.url;
    if (filePath == './')
        filePath = './index.html';
    if (filePath == './CHAT')
        filePath = './chatform.html';

    var extname = String(path.extname(filePath)).toLowerCase();
    var contentType = 'text/html';
    var mimeTypes = {
        '.html': 'text/html',
        '.js': 'text/javascript',
        '.css': 'text/css',
        '.json': 'application/json',
        '.png': 'image/png',
        '.jpg': 'image/jpg',
        '.gif': 'image/gif',
    };

    contentType = mimeTypes[extname] || 'application/octect-stream';

    fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
        if (error) {
            if(error.code == 'ENOENT'){
                fs.readFile('./404.html', function(error, content) {
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                });
            }
            else {
                response.writeHead(500);
                response.end('Sorry, check with the site admin for error: '+error.code+' ..\n');
                response.end();
            }
        }
        else {
            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            response.end(content, 'utf-8');
        }
    });

}).listen(9020);
console.log('Server running on port 9020');
```

Comment: Have you considered using the socket.io for chat implementation? Since it is using websockets, both your web app and chat would easily work on the very same port.

Comment: Use a certain path prefix for all chat requests and another path prefix for all file request and then use a single server where you check the path prefix on the request to decide which type of request it is an then branch your code accordingly.